# Как настроить редирект с index.php на / в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Пытаюсь настроить редирект с **index.php** на **/** через `.htaccess` таким образом:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTPS/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://vipstroyka.by/.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Проблема в том, что на главной странице редирект с **index.php** на **/** работает, а на вложенных – нет. Как сделать, чтобы например с https://vipstroyka.by/prod/index.php или https://vipstroyka.by/prod/index.html редиректило на https://vipstroyka.by/prod/ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Для всех индексных страниц на сайте:**

```
   RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html)$ https://vipstroyka.by/prod/ [R=301,L]
```

**Или же вручную:**

```
   Redirect 301 /prod/index.php https://vipstroyka.by/prod/
   Redirect 301 /prod/index.html https://vipstroyka.by/prod/
```

Comment: Как сделать чтобы с любой страницы с index.php или index.html редиректило на /